# How to get last numeric digit from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to get last digit from a string in javascript.

**Note that I am not looking to get the last character on a string, but the last *digit* as a *number***

For example:

```
lastDigit("MA01A"); // returns 1
lastDigit("MA01"); // returns 1
lastDigit("1"); // returns 1
lastDigit("1MABC"); // returns 1
lastDigit("MABC"); // returns undefined
```

How can I get it?

Comment: What research have you done into this string manipulation question?  I ask this, because this is a very basic question that should have solutions already or resources available on any search engine

Comment: `const source="MA01"; let char = source[source.length-1]; console.log(char);`

Comment: Not duplicate..pls understnad

Comment: @Xatenev and the others, the last *number* inside a string, not any last character.

Comment: In your example the last *number* & last *character* are the same thing, is an input where there is a number followed by one or more letters possible?

Comment: @Xatenev please reopen this question. This is not a duplicate as the linked question is a different question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, mbuechmann This question is entirely unclear and can't be answered at its current state. With the current input => output that's given, the referenced question adresses this problem. The alternative would be just closing it without referencing a topic that _might_ help OP out. It might make sense to re-open this question again if OP provided more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of this that doesn't use a for loop. Two versions: a short one, returning a string, and a slightly longer one returning a number, in case you need that too.

```js
function lastDigit(str) {
  // Remove all non-digits from the string and return the last
  // character
  return str.replace(/[^\d]*/g, '').slice(-1) || undefined;
}

function lastDigitAsNumber(str) {
  // Remove all non-digits from the string
  const digit = str.replace(/[^\d]*/g, '').slice(-1)
  // Parse the last digit as number (this will be 0 for ''
  const number = Number(digit)
  // Return accordingly
  return digit.length > 0 ? number : undefined;
}

console.log(lastDigit("MA01A")); // returns '1'
console.log(lastDigit("MA01")); // returns '1'
console.log(lastDigit("1")); // returns '1'
console.log(lastDigit("1MABC")); // returns '1'
console.log(lastDigit("MABC")); // returns undefined

console.log(lastDigitAsNumber("MA01A")); // returns 1
console.log(lastDigitAsNumber("MA01")); // returns 1
console.log(lastDigitAsNumber("1")); // returns 1
console.log(lastDigitAsNumber("1MABC")); // returns 1
console.log(lastDigitAsNumber("MABC")); // returns undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you may have non-numerical characters at the end of the string, you can traverse the string in reverse and return the first number you encounter, or (e.g.) `null` otherwise

```js
function getLatestDigit(text) {
  for (var i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!isNaN(text.charAt(i))) return text.charAt(i);
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(getLatestDigit("MA01"));
console.log(getLatestDigit("MA12aaaaa"));
console.log(getLatestDigit("NoNumbersHere"));
```

Comment: This is the best method imo, the RegEx solutions are significant overkill for this trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```js
var source="MA01";

var lastNum = source.replace(/.*?(\d+)[^\d]*$/,'$1')

alert(lastNum);
```

Comment: Try it with "MA01aaaaaaaaaaa". Given the example you're not wrong (and the question is unclear about the input) but if we take the title of the question literally this doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var source = "MA01",
    lastNum = source.match(/(\d+)(?!.*\d)/)[0];

alert(lastNum);
```

Comment: Try adding a letter at the end of the string. It throws an error. See my comment to the other answer for why I'm pointing this out.

Comment: And this returns `1` but only because it parses `01`, what if the input ended `12`?

Comment: Now you're returning `01`.